# Adjacent Elements in MATLAB with Mathematical Formulation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, combinatorics

I have a set [image: N = {1,2,3,4] with [image: n=4] elements and the possible adjacent combinations for this are:

[image: {empty set} {1} {2} {3} {4} {1,2} {2,3} {3,4} {1,2,3} {2,3,4} and {1,2,3,4}]

So the total possible combinations are c=11 which can be calculated with the formula:

[image: c=(n^2/2)+(n/2)+1]

I can model this using a [image: A = n X c] as below whose elements can be represented as a(n,c) are:

[image: Matrix A]

I have tried to implement this in MATLAB, but since I have hard-coded the above math my code is not extensible for cases where `n > 4`:

```
n=4;
c=((n^2)/2)+(n/2)+1;
A=zeros(n,c); 

for i=1:n 
    A(i,i+1)=1; 
end 

for i=1:n-1 
    A(i,n+i+1)=1;
    A(i+1,n+i+1)=1;
end 

for i=1:n-2 
    A(i,n+i+4)=1;
    A(i+1,n+i+4)=1;
    A(i+2,n+i+4)=1; 
end 

for i=1:n-3 
    A(i,n+i+6)=1;
    A(i+1,n+i+6)=1;
    A(i+2,n+i+6)=1;
    A(i+3,n+i+6)=1;
end
```

Is there a relatively low complexity method to transform this problem in MATLAB with *n* number of elements of set *N*, following my above mathematical formulation?

Comment: What's your actual question here? It looks like you have a solution already, no?

Comment: Are you asking how this would extend to other arbitrary sets?

Comment: Yes I have a solution already but I am new to MATLAB and I want to program it in the MATLAB as an algorithm. How can I program it?

Comment: You would first need to figure out how you would extend this to other arbitrary sets (without needing Matlab).  I think I see how this would generalize, but it's not entirely clear (especially the ordering for the possible adjacent combinations).

Comment: In the above example and MATLAB code below I have done it for n=4. But I want to do it for any n elements. My code doesnt work with n elements. You will be appreciated if you suggest me how to do it for any number n in.
MATLAB CODE:
clc
n=4;
c=((n^2)/2)+(n/2)+1;
A=zeros(n,c); 
for i=1:n
    A(i,i+1)=1;
end
for i=1:n-1
    A(i,n+i+1)=1;
    A(i+1,n+i+1)=1;
end
for i=1:n-2
    A(i,n+i+4)=1;
    A(i+1,n+i+4)=1;
    A(i+2,n+i+4)=1;
end

for i=1:n-3
    A(i,n+i+6)=1;
    A(i+1,n+i+6)=1;
    A(i+2,n+i+6)=1;
    A(i+3,n+i+6)=1;
end

Comment: @Amigo Please add updates directly to your question using [edit] rather than adding them in comments. As you see, code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to go about this is to take a bit pattern with the first `k` bits set and shift it down `n - k` times, saving each shifted column vector to the result. So, starting from

```
1
0
0
0
```

Shift 1, 2, and 3 times to get

```
|1 0 0 0|
|0 1 0 0|
|0 0 1 0|
|0 0 0 1|
```

We'll use [`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) to achieve this.

```
function A = adjcombs(n)
   c = (n^2 + n)/2 + 1;   % number of combinations
   A = zeros(n,c);        % preallocate output array 

   col_idx = 1;             % skip the first (all-zero) column 
   curr_col = zeros(n,1);   % column vector containing current combination
   for elem_count = 1:n
      curr_col(elem_count) = 1;   % add another element to our combination
      for shift_count = 0:(n - elem_count)
         col_idx = col_idx + 1;   % increment column index 
         % shift the current column and insert it at the proper index
         A(:,col_idx) = circshift(curr_col, shift_count);
      end
   end
end
```

Calling the function with `n = 4 and 6` we get:

```
>> A = adjcombs(4)
A =

   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1
   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1

>> A = adjcombs(6)
A =

   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1
```

Comment: I just edited the OP's question to include the code he put in the comments, but it seems you've presented a complete solution to the OP's question already. I'm not sure why he hasn't accepted your answer.